# What does "days += 1" mean in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

I cannot follow this code, and was hoping someone can explain it to me

```
def negative(temperatures):
    days = 0
    for t in temperatures:
        if t < 0:
            days += 1
    return days
```

Can someone please explain line 5?

So from what I understand the function scans for negative temperatures in the array '`temperatures`', assigns  the first index that is `<0` to `t`,  and then line 5 takes `days`, which `= 0`, and then adds `1` to it, why does this equal one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean += in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721192/what-does-it-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notionally a += b "adds" b to a,storing the result in a.

> Syntax:
>
> **A += B**

A: Any valid object.

B: Any valid object.

**Equivalent to A = A + B.**

```
days += 1
```

is the same as

```
days = days + 1
```

**Note:**

you are using here variable days like "counter" (you are counting how much days had temterature <0)

you have list of temperatures ,probably something like :
temperatures = [3,18,-2,4,-6]

you are passing over all items in your list temperatures:

```
for t in temperatures:
```

you are checking every item if its less than 0:

```
if t < 0:
```

if temperature is negative: 
variable days(started from 0) will increase for 1

for exemple:
in first step days = 0

```
days = days + 1 -> 0+1 = 1
```

in next step days = 1

```
days = days + 1 -> 1+1 = 2
```

in next step days = 2

```
days = days + 1 -> 2+1 = 3
```

> NOTE : **difference between = and ==**
>
> **OPERATOR =**    Assign value of right side of expression to left side operand, its not relational operators which compare if both operands
>   are equal, that is **==**

example:

```
myNumber = 5
```

This assigns 5 to variable myNumber.

```
if (myNumber == 5):
   print(myNumber)
```

This tests for equality.  The two use are not interchangeable.