# What does += mean in this context?

Tags: python, string, list

```
def get_initials(fullname):
  xs = (fullname)
  name_list = xs.split()

  initials = ""

  for name in name_list:  # go through each name
    initials += name[0].upper()  # append the initial
    ##       ^^ what is happening here?

  return initials
```

What is the `+=` in this context?  Is it incrementing the value in the list?

Comment: there is no increment in this code, `+=` is not increment, but string concatenation here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean += in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721192/what-does-it-mean-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

The line `initials += name[0].upper() # append the initial` adds the first character to a string, the process:

1. Split a string into a list (So `john doe` becomes `['john', 'doe']`)
2. Iterate over each item in that list
3. For each item in that list, append to the empty string the first character, capitialized
   For example, for `john`, get the first character `j` and capitalize it as `J`
4. Return the initials (`JD` in this case)