# Django reverse function arguments

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and Django and am trying to determine how the following code works:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('poll_results', args=(p.id,)))
```

Specifically the 2nd argument of the reverse function. It looks like it is setting the parameter of args equal to a tuple. Why do I need an extra comma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(p.id)` is just `p.id` in parentheses, `(p.id,)` is a single-element tuple.

[Parenthesized forms](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms) in docs

Answer (score 3):

The trailing comma is required if a tuple only has one item to differentiate a tuple from stylistic parenthesis.

Similar questions:
[Python tuple comma syntax rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992559/python-tuple-comma-syntax-rule)
[Why does adding a trailing comma after a string make it a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750632/why-does-adding-a-trailing-comma-after-a-string-make-it-a-tuple)