# How to extract dictionary single key-value pair in variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

I have only a single key-value pair in a dictionary. I want to assign key to one variable
and it's value to another variable. I have tried with below ways but I am getting error for same.

```
>>> d = {"a": 1}

>>> d.items()
[('a', 1)]

>>> (k, v) = d.items()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

>>> (k, v) = list(d.items())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I know that we can extract key and value one by one, or by for loop and `iteritems()`, but isn't there a simple way such that we can assign both in a single statement?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Add another level, with a tuple (just the comma):

```
(k, v), = d.items()
```

or with a list:

```
[(k, v)] = d.items()
```

or pick out the first element:

```
k, v = d.items()[0]
```

The first two have the added advantage that they throw an exception if your dictionary has more than one key, and both work on Python 3 while the latter would have to be spelled as `k, v = next(iter(d.items()))` to work.

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> (k, v), = d.items()
>>> k, v
('foo', 'bar')
>>> [(k, v)] = d.items()
>>> k, v
('foo', 'bar')
>>> k, v = d.items()[0]
>>> k, v
('foo', 'bar')
>>> k, v = next(iter(d.items()))  # Python 2 & 3 compatible
>>> k, v
('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters, what's the technical explanation behind : `(k, v), = d.items()`. I cannot get my head around the last comma.

Comment: @dmeu: it is a tuple assignment, the comma [makes the left-hand side target a tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750632/why-does-adding-a-trailing-comma-after-a-variable-name-make-it-a-tuple).

Comment: @MartijnPieters And what is on the right-hand side? :) I mean why does it no twork without the comma?

Comment: @dmeu: why not *try it out*? `dict.items()` returns an iterable *containing* `(key, value)` pairs. What do you think happens with `foo = dict.items()` vs. `foo, = dict.items()`? The first binds `foo` to whatever `dict.items()` returns (a list in Python 2, a dictionary view in Python 3). `foo, = dict.items()` binds `foo` to the *first element* in the `dict.items()` sequence and throws an exception if there are 0 or more than 1 elements in that sequence.

Comment: @dmeu: `(k, v), = d.items()` just takes that one step further. Take the first item, a `(key, value)` pair, and assign that to `(k, v)`.

Comment: Whats up with the second comma in the "(k, v), = d.items()" ?

Comment: @quantum231: why not try and see what happens if you removed it? As my answer states, you could replace it with `[(k, v)] = d.items()`, that does exactly the same thing: unpack `d.items()` into a single key and value pair. This is called *tuple unpacking*, or *iterable unpacking*.

Answer (score 6):

`items()` returns a list of tuples so:

```
(k,v) = d.items()[0]
```

Comment: Indexing not supported on Python3

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> d = {"a":1}
>>> [(k, v)] = d.items()
>>> k
'a'
>>> v
1
```

Or using `next`, `iter`:

```
>>> k, v = next(iter(d.items()))
>>> k
'a'
>>> v
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
d = {"a": 1}
```

you can do

```
k, v = d.keys()[0], d.values()[0]
```

`d.keys()` will actually return list of all keys and `d.values()` return list of all values, since you have a single key:value pair in `d` you will be accessing the first element in list of keys and values

Comment: you cannot subscribe to dict_keys anymore... you'll get: TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 3):

**In Python 3:**

Short answer:

```
[(k, v)] = d.items()
```

or:

```
(k, v) = list(d.items())[0]
```

or:

```
(k, v), = d.items()
```

Long answer:

`d.items()`, basically (but not actually) gives you a list with a tuple, which has 2 values, that will look like this when printed:

```
dict_items([('a', 1)])
```

You can convert it to the actual list by wrapping with `list()`, which will result in this value:

```
[('a', 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.popitem()` method.

```
k, v = d.popitem()
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `popitem` will also remove the key-value pair from the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

This is best if you have many items in the dictionary, since it doesn't actually create a list but yields just one key-value pair.

```
k, v = next(d.iteritems())
```

Of course, if you have more than one item in the dictionary, there's no way to know which one you'll get out.

Answer (score 2):

**In Python 3**

The easiest (most terse) answer is probably:

```
k, = d.keys()
```

Example:

```
>>> d = {"a": 1}
>>> k, = d.keys()
>>> k
'a'
```

The same idea can be applied for `values()` and `items()` as well:

```
>>> v, = d.values()
>>> v
1

>>> (k, v), = d.items()
>>> k
'a'
>>> v
1
```

You'll get the same benefits mentioned above, i.e. `ValueError` if your `dict` has more than 1 key:

```
>>> d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
>>> k, = d.keys()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

**Additional Details**

There was also some confusion about the trailing comma (`,`) in `k, = d.keys()`. Though it's unsolicited (and off-topic), here's the best way I can explain it.

The trailing comma is simply notation for "expression list" assignment (a.k.a "tuple assignment"). Without it, you'll just have assigned a `dict_keys` object instead of the value of the first (and only) value contained by that same object:

```
>>> k = d.keys()
>>> k
dict_keys(['a'])
```

Specifics can be found in [The Python Language Reference, 7. Simple statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#:%7E:text=If%20the%20target%20list%20is%20a%20single%20target%20with%20no%20trailing%20comma%2C%20optionally%20in%20parentheses%2C%20the%20object%20is%20assigned%20to%20that%20target.) (although that document is a little too dense, for my taste).

Basically, multiple variables can be unpacked (or assigned) to multiple variables on a single line as long as a 1-to-1 assignment is preserved (unless using starred assignment `*`).

```
>>> (a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a
1
```

And because parentheses are optional, the following is equivalent:

```
>>> a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
>>> b
2
```

Because `(a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3)` <==> `a, b, c = 1, 2, 3`, the same list assigment expression can be used for single item, except tuples with a single item ***must have a trailing comma***.

Without it, the parentheses are evaluated as an expression, and assign the contained resulting value:

```
>>> t = (1)
>>> type(t)
<class 'int'>
>>> t
1
```

While this can seem strange at first, but if you look a `repr()` of a `tuple` with a single item, you'll see it is consistently represented with a trailing comma:

```
>>> tuple([1])
(1,)

>>> t = ('a',)
>>> type(t)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> t
('a',)
```

That being said, syntactically, you can *technically* perform a tuple assignment with a single item with (or without) the optional parenthesis, just so long as you include the trailing comma:

```
# weird, but okay...
>>> (a,) = (1,)
>>> a
1

# technically, sure... but please don't do this.
>>> a, = 1,
>>> a
1
```

In fact, assigning any value with a trailing comma is evaluated a tuple:

```
# assignment with a trailing comma (without parentheses)
>>> t = 1,
>>> type(t)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> t
(1,)
```

While this syntax seems strange, and isn't commonly used, it **does** pop up from time to time to solve uncommon problems (like this one).

If it helps, you can always include optional parenthesis, because "[Explicit is better than implicit.](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/#:%7E:text=Explicit%20is%20better%20than%20implicit.)":

```
# original example
>>> d = {"a": 1}

# get (only) key
>>> (k,) = d.keys()
>>> k
'a'

# get (only) value
>>> (v,) = d.values()
>>> v
1

# get (only) key and value
>>> ((k, v),) = d.items()
>>> k
'a'
>>> v
1
```

Hope that helps.

**TL;DR**

Q: How do you [unpack] a [key||value] from a `dict` with a single item?

A: Creatively, with sweet [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar#:%7E:text=things%20can%20be%20expressed%20more%20clearly%2C%20more%20concisely%2C%20or%20in%20an%20alternative%20style%20that%20some%20may%20prefer), baby!

Answer (score 1):

You have a list. You must index the list in order to access the elements.

```
(k,v) = d.items()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the dictionary key and don't care about the value, note that `(key, ), = foo.items()` doesn't work. You do need to assign that value to a variable.

So you need `(key, _), = foo.items()`

Illustration in Python 3.7.2:

```
>>> foo = {'a': 1}
>>> (key, _), = foo.items()
>>> key
'a'
>>> (key, ), = foo.items()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
key = list(foo.keys())[0]
value = foo[key]
```