# How to get single value from dict with single entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I saw [How to extract dictionary single key-value pair in variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145902/how-to-extract-dictionary-single-key-value-pair-in-variables) suggesting:

```
d = {"a":1}
(k, v), = d.items()
```

But: I only care about the *value*. And I want to pass that value to a method; like:

```
foo(v)
```

So the question is: is there a simple command that works for both python2 and python3 that gives me that value directly, without the detour of the "tuple" assignment?

Or is there a way to make the tuple assignment work for my usecase of calling a method?

Comment: `v, = d.values()` works fine in both Py2 and 3, you'd obviously need to unpack before invoking the function.

Comment: At first I thought this is simple. I mean just get the value using the key but then I got it. You do not know the key. I found this which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097866/access-an-arbitrary-element-in-a-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`list(d.values())[0]` will be evaluated to 1.
As pointed out in the comments, the cast to `list` is only needed in python3.

`next(iter(d.values()))` is another possibility (probably more memory efficient, as you do not need to create a list)

Both solution testes locally with python 3.6.0 and in [TIO with python 2](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@iYKtQrZ6obmVYy1VQlJlXopCTWVyikaJXlphTmlqsoakZbRALlclLrSjRyCxJLUKW1vz/HwA).

Comment: Why you convert list with `list()` again?

Comment: @WiriyaRungruang `d.values()` is no `list` : it's a `dict_values` object, which does not support indexing. But as it's iterable, it can be converted to `list`, which supports indexing.

Comment: @B.Barbieri `d.values()[0]` and `list(d.values())[0]` I get the same results and `type(d.values())` it's show `<type 'list'>`

Comment: @WiriyaRungruang you're right ... on python 2. On python 3.6.0, it shows `<class 'dict_values'>`.

Answer (score 15):

`next(iter(d.values()))` is the natural way to extract the only value from a dictionary. Conversion to `list` just to extract the only element is not necessary.

It is also performs best of the available options (tested on Python 3.6):

```
d = [{'a': i} for i in range(100000)]

%timeit [next(iter(i.values())) for i in d]  # 50.1 ms per loop
%timeit [list(i.values())[0] for i in d]     # 54.8 ms per loop
%timeit [list(i.values()).pop() for i in d]  # 81.8 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 6):

> is there a way to make the tuple assignment work for my usecase

```
v, *_ = d.values()
```

Extended unpacking will do the job in Python 3, failing with a `ValueError: Not enough values to unpack` if `d` is empty. Extended unpacking is not available in Python 2.

Answer (score 5):

Using `more_itertools.one` is short, and also validates that there is a single entry

```py
In [1]: from more_itertools import one
   ...: d = {"a":5}
   ...: one(d.values())
Out[1]: 5
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know the key then you can simply do :

```html
d["a"] 
output :
1
```

and if you don't know the key:

```html
for key in d.keys():
d[key]

#so basically you have to do :

for key in d.keys():
f00(d[key])
```

Answer (score 2):

> is there a simple command that works for both python2 and python3 that
>   gives me that value directly, without the detour of the "tuple"
>   assignment?

The solution using `dict.copy()`(to preserve the original dict) and `dict.popitem()` functions:

```
d = {"a":1}
foo(d.copy().popitem()[1])
```

Comment: This the need to make a copy in order to avoid changing the original severely limits the usefulness of this approach, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

For your `foo(v)` use case, you can directly unpack the value into the call:

```
foo(*d.values())
```

Demo:

```py
def foo(x):
    print(x)

d = {"a": 1}

(k, v), = d.items()
foo(v)

foo(*d.values())
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3Q1JS0xTS8vM1KjStuBSAoKAoM68EyOPiSlGwVahWSlSyUjCs5eLSyNZRKNPUAYql6GWWpOYWa2hygfSVAVWCaK0UvbLEnNJUoLgmxGyoFTCrAA)):

```
1
1
```