# Python MySQL field update

Tags: python, mysql

I am simply trying to increment field value by 1. It spit the error that had to do something with long value of object sequence_id

```
db.execute('SELECT id FROM sstudio_queues_sequence')
        sequence_id = db.fetchone()[0]
        sequence_id = sequence_id + 1
        db.execute("UPDATE sstudio_queues_sequence SET id=%s", (sequence_id))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `db.execute` [should be a *sequence*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) (or mapping), not a scalar value:

```
db.execute("UPDATE sstudio_queues_sequence SET id=%s", 
           [sequence_id])
```

You could use a tuple, (e.g. `(sequence_id,)`), or a list (e.g. `[sequence_id]`, as shown above).

With paretheses only, `(sequence_id)` is evaluated to the same thing as `sequence_id`. It is the [comma after `sequence_id` which makes `(sequence_id,)` a tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3750632/190597).

Comment: Thank you, I am gonna try it.

Comment: wait is there a reason why you dropped the second part of the argument to the next line and indent it ?

Comment: I put `[sequence_id]` on the second line only so that the important part of the solution (as formatted by StackOverflow) shows up clearly, not requiring viewers to use the scrollbar to find the answer. (See also ["implied line continuation" in the PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).)