# Query on the below Python Output

Tags: python

I am printing the list variable as:

```
lst=("Python",)*3
print(lst)
lst=("Python")*3
print(lst)
```

and the output is

```
('Python', 'Python', 'Python')
PythonPythonPython
```

Definitely the output is different due to the comma(,) used in the first print statement. But the first statement does not have two values either.

Can someone describe the technical reason behind this?

Comment: `("Python",)` creates a 1-tuple and `("Python")` is just a string in brackets. In fact, the brackets don't do anything here,  just `"Python",` will create the same tuple. As a side note, `()` will create an empty tuple.

Comment: Adding the comma just makes it a tuple. `("1", "2") * 2` = `("1", "2", "1", "2")`

Comment: This page has a bit more detail on tuple syntax, https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax.

Comment: Thanks @Wright, This solve my confusion

Comment: Thanks @eugenhu for clearing my confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

A trailing `,` creates a [`tuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750632/why-does-adding-a-trailing-comma-after-a-variable-name-make-it-a-tuple)

#### Tuples:

```
"Python",
```

is a tuple of length 1, so

```
lst=("Python",)*3
```

Is a tuple of length 3:

```
('Python', 'Python', 'Python')
```

#### Strings:

```
("Python")
```

is a string, and thus:

```
lst=("Python")*3
```

is a string that is repeated three times:

```
PythonPythonPython
```