# Scrapy - TypeError: 'Rule' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, typeerror, scrapy

I was trying to scrape the titles from this website(https://minerals.usgs.gov/science/mineral-deposit-database/#products). I am using a crawl spider beacuse I intend to get more information from every url in the page later on!

but got a TypeError: 'Rule' object is not iterable! 
This is the code that I used:

```
import scrapy
import datetime
import socket
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from usgs.items import MineralItem
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class MineralSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mineral'
    allowed_domains = ['web']
    start_urls = 'https://minerals.usgs.gov/science/mineral-deposit- 
    database/#products'

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="products"][1]/p/a'),
            callback='parse')
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        it = ItemLoader(item=MineralItem(), response=response)
        it.add_xpath('name', '//*[@class="container"]/header/h1/text()')
        it.add_value('url', response.url)
        it.add_value('project', self.settings.get('BOT_NAME'))
        it.add_value('spider', self.name)
        it.add_value('server', socket.gethostname())
        it.add_value('date', datetime.datetime.now())
        return it.load_item()
```

**LOG MESSAGE:**

```
(base) C:\Users\User\Documents\Python WebCrawling Learing 
Projects\usgs\usgs\spiders>scrapy crawl mineral
2018-11-16 17:43:03 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: 
usgs)
2018-11-16 17:43:03 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 
2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 
3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)], 
pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, Platform 
Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
2018-11-16 17:43:03 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 
'usgs', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'usgs.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 
'SPIDER_MODULES': ['usgs.spiders']}
2018-11-16 17:43:03 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2018-11-16 17:43:03 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

2018-11-16 17:43:03 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
result = g.send(result)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 
79, in crawl
self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 
102, in _create_spider
return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\crawl.py", 
line 100, in from_crawler
spider = super(CrawlSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 51, in from_crawler
spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\crawl.py", 
line 40, in __init__
self._compile_rules()
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\crawl.py", 
line 92, in _compile_rules
self._rules = [copy.copy(r) for r in self.rules]
TypeError: 'Rule' object is not iterable
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a comma after your `Rule` object, so that it considers that it's a valid tuple:

```
rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(
            restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="products"][1]/p/a'),
            callback='parse'),
)
```

You may want to take a look at this answer as well: [Why does adding a trailing comma after a variable name make it a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750632/why-does-adding-a-trailing-comma-after-a-variable-name-make-it-a-tuple)