# Creating sets using loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

Could anybody please help me understand the below statement in the code below it?

```
cartesian_powers = [ i+(a,) for i in cartesian_powers for a in A]
```

Specifically the role of `i+(a,)`?

Please explain the answer as much as possible.

Code:

```
A = {1, 2, 3}
k = 2

# Initialize every element as a tuple
cartesian_powers = [(a,) for a in A]

for j in range(k-1):
    cartesian_powers = [ i+(a,) for i in cartesian_powers for a in A]

print("Tuples  in {}^{}: {}".format(A,k,set(cartesian_powers)))
print("Size = {}".format(len(cartesian_powers)))
```

Comment: What exactly do you need explained? Do you not understand what `(a,)` means (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750632/why-does-adding-a-trailing-comma-after-a-variable-name-make-it-a-tuple) for an explanation)? Or you're wondering why it's being used in that way? Regardless, when you don't understand code, I **HIGHLY** recommend stepping through the code line-by-line in a debugger. PyCharm is free and has a great debugger, [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html) is some info about it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `cartesian_powers` is initialized using the same `(a,)` syntax, indicating the elements are tuples, each containing a single integer.

In `[ i+(a,) for i in cartesian_powers for a in A]`, `i` and `(a,)` are each tuples, so the addition `i+(a,)` *concatenates the tuples, returning a two-integer tuple.

I think the addition syntax `i+(a,)` to represent tuple concatenation is causing the confusion.