# Expected type 'str', Tuple[str] was returned in python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, type-hinting

Expected type `str`, `Tuple[str]` was returned in python3.8

```
CA2 = "2CA",
CA3 = "3CA",
CA4 = "4CA",
LTE = "LTE"
def temp() -> str:
    ca_list = [1, 2, 3]
    if len(ca_list) == 1:
        result = LTE
    elif len(ca_list) == 2:
        result = CA4
    elif len(ca_list) == 3:
        result = CA2
    else:
        result = CA3
    return result
temp()
```

output: `('2CA',)`

Comment: What is the question?  You state the function returns a str, but then you return `"2CA",` which is tuple.

Comment: putting comma after "2CA" makes your variable 'CA2' a tuple and that is being returned.

Comment: why ('2CA',) was returned, corrent return is 2CA.

Comment: ("2CA",) and your variable `CA2="2CA",` are the same.

Answer (score 2):

The comma after each automatically converts the string such as `"2CA"` to a tuple like `('2CA',)` so therefore your output is a tuple containing it.

if you want a string output just remove the commas

see here:
[Why does adding a trailing comma after a variable name make it a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750632/why-does-adding-a-trailing-comma-after-a-variable-name-make-it-a-tuple)