# Trying to compare output value from a dictionary to a number I am getting error- TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python. I am learning through this 100 days video tutorial from Udemy. However surprisingly same code worked for the tutor on video but not for me. **After going through current posts with similar error I couldn't figure out the solution and decided to post my question. I have checked in Thonny debugger an code- bid_amnt = bidding_record[bidder] is where value comes with the coma at the end. I have tried converting it to integer by int(bidding_record[bidder]) also but it didn't work**. Please tell me how to correct.

```
#Code snippet
def find_highest_bidder(bidding_record):
    #bidding_record = {Angela:123, James:321} examlpe of dictionary prepared
    highest_bid = 0
    winner = ""
    for bidder in bidding_record:   
        bid_amnt = bidding_record[bidder]
        if bid_amnt > highest_bid:
            highest_bid = bid_amnt
            winner = bidder
  print(f"Winner of this bid is {winner} with ${highest_bid}")

#Declaring variable for loop and empty dictionary
bid_on = True

while bid_on == True:
    #Taking user Inputs
    name = input("Please enter your name: \n")
    bid_value = int(input("please enter your bid amount: $"))
    other_users = input("are there other users who want to bid type yes/no:  \n").lower() 
    bid_dict[name] = bid_value,
  
    #Calling function by passing dictionary in argument  
    find_highest_bidder(bid_dict)
  
    #Calling clear function from replit if there are no more users  
    if other_users == "no":
        bid_on = False
    else:
    clear()
```

Comment: udemy videos also has Q&A, what was the response there from instructor? here in SO, a minimal reproducible example would help someone  to provide the answer

Comment: Where do you define `bid_dict`? Also which line is throwing the error? You should be able to see where the error is occurring to debug it.

Comment: `bid_dict[name] = bid_value,` assigns a tuple as your dictionary value.  Get rid of that comma.

Comment: Based on the shown code, the trailing comma at `bid_dict[name] = bid_value,` makes no sense and causes the problem.

Comment: I have checked in Thonny debugger an code: bid_amnt = bidding_record[bidder] is where it throws error, I have not posted it on Udemy I will do there as well. However I hope to get help here please.

Comment: Changing `bid_dict[name] = bid_value,` to `bid_dict[name] = bid_value` will make your code work fine

Comment: Hi codester09 the change you have suggested are same as previous I guessed something left off

Comment: Hi  Michael Butscher, You are spot on, even my opinion is same but just don't know how to correct it. I am also not aware of Tuples or how to add it in dictionary so going through it but at this moment I am looking for how to correct my code.

Comment: Hey Guys please tell me how can I remove trailing comma here, I tried using rstrip() but didnt work and I got following mesage- bid_amnt = bid_amnt.rstrip(',')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what happened. In the line `bid_dict[name] = bid_value,` you are defining `bid_dict[name]` to be a tuple since `bid_value` has a `,` after it.

In python, whenever you put a comma after a variable like this, it expects it to be a tuple and converts it to that datatype.

Then in the line `if bid_amnt > highest_bid:` it is trying to compare `bid_amnt` which is the `tuple` you defined above with `bid_value,` to the `int` you defined as `highest_bid = 0`

Remove that comma and it should work.

Comment: Hello Abinitio, Please guide me how to achieve it I tried rstrip() but it says bid_amnt = bid_amnt.rstrip(',')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Comment: Just erase the comma from the code. Instead of writing `bid_dict[name] = bid_value,` just write `bid_dict[name] = bid_value`

Comment: Thanks a tons abinitio, it was so stupid of me and python was not giving me proper reply. I owe you one.

Comment: No problem. Here's a question that addresses this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750632/why-does-adding-a-trailing-comma-after-an-expression-create-a-tuple